# FROM keyword not found in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g

I am using Oracle 11g client.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3 Salary FROM employees ORDER BY Salary DESC;
```

Giving error

> FROM keyword not found where expected.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please have a look at [editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) on how to properly format your questions. Have a look at [SQL distinct](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp), it might help you to ask a more specific question.

Comment: Where have you seen `TOP` in the Oracle documentation?

Comment: I wasn't sure about the use of top in oracle.

Answer (score 0):

In **Oracle11g** i guess you need to use `DISTINCT` like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Salary FROM employees ORDER BY Salary DESC) WHERE rownum < 4
```

Here `rownum` works like `TOP` provided with the condition `< 4` or you can pass `rownum <= 3`

Comment: That's helpful. Thank you.